# double click is not working after 1st time

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a MVC site and I have a html table and on double click on a cell it will go to edit mode and for the first time it works and next time when I double on the same cell or any other cell it dosen't work, when I make a click anywhere and then if I do double click it works fine.

I suspect some conflict between single click and double click.

```
$('#TableOverride tr:gt(0)').each(function () {
$(this).find('td:eq(9)').dblclick(function () {
EditCell(this, 9);
});
});
```

Update : Tested in Chrome and it works fine without any issues, it looks like a browser issue with IE 11 and earlier versions.

```
function EditCell(thisCell, colNum) {
    var Id;

    // if the table cell is not in edit mode
    if ($(thisCell).find('input').length == 0) {
        if (colNum == 4 && $(thisCell).parent().parent().parent()[0].id == 'OverrideTable') {
             myBlk = $(thisCell).html();
            $(thisCell).html('<input type="text" data-oldvalue="' + myBlk + '" />');
            $(thisCell).find('input').val(myBlk);
            $(thisCell).find('input').trigger('focus');
            $(thisCell).find('input').keypress(function (e) {
                if (e.which == 13) {

                    // If Enter key is pressed, update data.
                    myBlk = $(this).val();
                    if (myBlk == '') {
                        $('div.errorSummary').html('my block cannot be empty!');
                        $('div.errorSummary').show();
                    } else {
                        Loadmyblk(myBlk, this);
LeaseOverrideObj.GetLeaseOverride());
                    }
            });
        }
```

Comment: I'm guessing your `EditCell()` function affects the HTML which removes the `dblclick` event handler on the cell itself. Can you please post the code of that function, and also the HTML too.

Comment: What this has to do with MVC?

Comment: Is your piece of code placed in another function?

Comment: @AnilKumar I am using MVC framework. if you don't know javascript it is fine

Answer (score 0):

Try this, it should work, add custom class e.g. "EditableCell" for using in dblclick event binding on document.

```
$('#TableOverride tr:gt(0)').each(
   function () {
         $(this).find('td:eq(9)').removeClass('EditableCell').addClass('EditableCell');
     });
});

$(document).on('dblclick', '.EditableCell', function()
        { EditCell(this, 9);
        });
```

Please note `$(document).on` should not be called in any loop, it should be called only once in `document.ready`.

[Js Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/anilk/tqyn3/2026/)

**Updated** [fiddle link to demo dblclick on dynamically added events](http://jsfiddle.net/anilk/tqyn3/2040/)

Comment: Not working at all. previously it used to work first time. what is EditableCell class??

Comment: Its working in IE-11 also, refer JS Fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/anilk/tqyn3/2026/ . "EditableCell" are custom class added for using in dblclick event binding on document.

Comment: the dblclick event with alert works fine as per your example, My application functionality is on dblclick it will create a dynamic textbox and I need to enter something and it will search and get the data and display during this process it will recreate all the html rows dynamically and somehow it unbind the dblclik event and it will not work

Comment: Binding on document, will be delegated to dynamically created element also, refer updated fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/anilk/tqyn3/2040/